# Multiple waiting approaches in #Appium

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, wait, appium-java

What is the best possible **Explicit Wait** implementation in Appium?

There are 3 possibilities I am aware of:

- Use wait `FluentWait` provided by *Selenium*
- Use `WebDriverWait` from *Selenium-Support* which internally extends `FluentWait` only
- Use *Appium's* native `AppiumFluentWait` which also extends `FluentWait` from *Selenium*.

Our framework is going through some major changes and this is the perfect time to make this future ready.

Current implementation is using, `WebDriverWait` but for this we have to explicitly add import for `selenium-support` library as Appium's implementation imports it in runtime only scopy.

Is there some issue using explicitly importing selenium-support library because of which Appium team thought of adding library import in this scope, could `AppiumFluentWait` be a better approach?

But Again appium has removed some common functions which are there in selenium ex: MobileElement with its new version, is this method prone to be removed in future?

Output for: `mvn dependency:tree`

```
 +- io.appium:java-client:jar:8.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:4.7.1:compile (version selected from constraint [4.7.0,5.0))
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:4.7.1:compile (version selected from constraint [4.7.0,5.0))
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.auto.service:auto-service-annotations:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.auto.service:auto-service:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.auto:auto-common:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.84.Final:linux-x86_64
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:4.1.84.Final:osx-x86_64
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-context:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-logging:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-metrics:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-logs:jar:1.19.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api-logs:jar:1.19.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-common:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure:jar:1.19.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-common:jar:1.19.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk-trace:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk:jar:1.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-semconv:jar:1.19.0-alpha:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.ous:jtoml:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client-netty-utils:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.60.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.60.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.60.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-http:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dev.failsafe:failsafe:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-json:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-manager:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:4.7.1:runtime (version selected from constraint [4.7.0,5.0))
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.5:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all it depends on the architecture.
Second, Do you really need FluentWait? The WebDriverWait class has optional arguments: timeout, poll_frequency, and ignored_exceptions and you could supply them there.

```
:Args:
            - driver - Instance of WebDriver (Ie, Firefox, Chrome or Remote)
            - timeout - Number of seconds before timing out
            - poll_frequency - sleep interval between calls
              By default, it is 0.5 second.
            - ignored_exceptions - iterable structure of exception classes ignored during calls.
              By default, it contains NoSuchElementException only.
```

How I see it:

1. wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
2. s_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
3. l_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
4. fl_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15, poll_frequency=1,
   ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException])
5. Then implement methods that return: waits

   def wait(self, locator, wait: WebDriverWait = None):
   if wait is None:
   wait = self._wait
   return wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(locator))

Then call the necessary method when it is needed, in general, it can be implemented within base class
An example in python, but you can reuse the logic